# django-like CRUD generation with JAVA EE6?

Tags: netbeans, jakarta-ee, crud, java-ee-6

I just checked out the Netbeans tutorial for auto-generation of CRUD pages. Not bad, but is there any way to generate CRUD pages with Java EE that look a bit more production like? For example like the admin interface generated by Django or Spring ROO. Of course basic features like searching or alphabetic ordering should be included.

Answer (score 1):

[Seam 3](http://seamframework.org/Seam3) is (or will be) very close to what you're looking for and should be able to  generate a full Java EE 6 based CRUD application from a database using the [`seam-gen` encore](http://seamframework.org/Documentation/Encore) tool. At least, that's part of the the vision. I don't know the exact status of Seam 3 and tools though.

#### Resources

- [Seam 3](http://seamframework.org/Seam3) project
- [Building Java EE 6 application using Seam](http://in.relation.to/service/File/15494) (PDF)
- [Chapter 11. Generate a CRUD Database Application](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/seam/html/crud_database_application.html) (for previous versions)